# Remove and Add Loopings between functions

Tags: c++

I have this problem where I made a looping in `int main` instead of `void displayinvoice`. I should put that `for loop` inside of the `void displayinvoice` because I just need to loop a certain part inside of the `displayinvoice` not all of the function. I tried so many things for almost 15 hours just for this. I found no solutions.. I really need help.

When I ran the code, the outputs only apply for the first input. For example :

````
ITEM ID : S1
PRICE PER UNIT : 300
QUANTITY : 5
DELIVERY COST : 15
TAX RATE : 0.1

ITEM NAME  : LION
ITEM ID : Ss
PRICE PER UNIT : 769
QUANTITY : 5
DELIVERY COST : 15
TAX RATE : 0.1

ITEM NAME  : KANGAROO
ITEM ID : S3
PRICE PER UNIT : 500
QUANTITY : 5
DELIVERY COST : 15
TAX RATE : 0.1```


The input should be like 
```ITEM ID      ITEM NAME      PRICE PER UNIT     QUANTITY       ROUGH COST
     S1            SHEEP          xxxxxx           xxxxx           xxxxx 
     S2            LION           xxxxxx           xxxxx           xxxxx
     S3            KANGAROO       xxxxxx           xxxxx           xxxxx ```


But what I got was :
```TEM ID      ITEM NAME      PRICE PER UNIT     QUANTITY       ROUGH COST
     S1            SHEEP          xxxxxx           xxxxx           xxxxx 
     S1            SHEEP          xxxxxx           xxxxx           xxxxx
     S1            SHEEP          xxxxxx           xxxxx           xxxxx ```


CODING BELOW :



```#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    
    struct item { 
    
    char itemname[50], id[5];
    float quantity;
    float price,taxrate,deliverycost;
    };
    
    
void dataread (item* items, int items_count){
    
    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
    {
    cout << " ITEM NAME          :";
    cin >> items[i].itemname;
    cout << " ITEM ID            :";
    cin >> items[i].id; 
    cout << " PRICE PER UNIT     :";
    cin >> items[i].price;
    cout << " QUANTITY           :";
    cin >> items[i].quantity;
    cout << " DELIVERY COST      :";
    cin >> items[i].deliverycost;
    cout << " TAX RATE           :";
    cin >> items[i].taxrate;
    cout <<"\n";
    }

}


struct CalculationResult {
    
    float roughtotalprice;
    float totaltax;
    float realprice;
};


CalculationResult calculation (item *i) {
    CalculationResult result;
      
    result.roughtotalprice = (i->price)*(i->quantity);
    result.totaltax = result.roughtotalprice*(i->taxrate);
    result.realprice = result.roughtotalprice+result.totaltax+(i->deliverycost); 
    return result;
}

void displayinvoice (item *i, int count){
    
    CalculationResult result = calculation(i);
    
    cout <<"                          **** INVOIS ****                                "<< endl;
    cout <<" ITEM ID" << " NAMA ITEM" <<" HARGA SEUNIT " <<" KUANTITI " << " JUMLAH KASAR"<<endl;
    
    for (int j = 0 ; j <count; ++j ) {
    
    cout <<"     "<< i->id<<"         "<< i->itemname <<"        "<< i->price <<"        "<< i->quantity<<"          " << result.roughtotalprice<<endl;
}
    
}
int main(){
    
    item items[3];
    int numberofItems = sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]);
    dataread(items,numberofItems);
    displayinvoice(items,numberofItems);

    
}```
````

Comment: what's the expected value and what errors did you get? Note that `items_count` is unused in the function

Comment: I just want to remove the loop from ``int main`` and add a loop to certain part inside of the ``displayinvoice`` function since I dont want to loop the whole ``displayinvoice`` function. The calculation seems to be okay.

Comment: Look at the dataread function. It already has what you need. Just use its prototype for displayinvoice function. Call displayinvoice function from the main the same way dataread is called.

Comment: `I tried so many things` show what you've tried here

Comment: I tried to remove the loop part in ``int main`` and added it to ``void display`` . Replaced the ``void displayinvoice`` from ``void displayinvoice (item i) `` to ``void displayinvoice (item* items, int items_count)`` . Still have errors..

Comment: What exactly is your *question*? What happened when you tried to run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? If you "have errors", what are the errors - please copy and paste the complete error messages, formatted like code.

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html). Then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). Read the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).  With GCC, compile with all warnings and debug info, so using `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Take inspiration from existing C++ open source projects (e.g. [fish](http://fishshell.com/)...)

Comment: the question is updated..

Comment: Reread my answer and also re-read the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Call displayinvoice function by referance, put it count number.

```
CalculationResult calculation(item *i)        
{     
    CalculationResult result;    
    result.roughtotalprice = (i->price)*(i->quantity);    
    result.totaltax = result.roughtotalprice*(i->taxrate);    
    result.realprice = result.roughtotalprice + result.totaltax + (i->deliverycost);    
    return result;    
}    

void displayinvoice(item *i, int count) {


    for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j) {
        CalculationResult result = calculation(i);

        cout << "                          **** INVOIS ****                                " << endl;


        cout << " ITEM ID        :" << i->id << endl;
        cout << " ITEM NAME      : " << i->itemname << endl;
        cout << " PRICE PER UNIT   : " << i->price << endl;
        cout << " QUANTITI : " << i->quantity << endl;
        cout << " ROUGH COST   : " << result.roughtotalprice << endl; // This one
        cout << " TOTAL PAYMENT : " << result.realprice << endl;
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {

    item items[3];
    int numberofItems = sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]);
    dataread(items, numberofItems);
    displayinvoice(items, numberofItems);
}
```

Comment: Please add English explanations in your answer and format your code properly: four spaces at least in front of every code line

Comment: It did work but when i put 3 different inputs, the output was only looping the first input i put. For example , ``1st input name = Chicken ``,``2nd lnput name = Cow``,``3rd lnput name = Goat``. 
The output produced : ```chicken``` for 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would suggest using a vector instead of a c-style array, for safety in general.
So you will need to `#include <vector>`.

Secondly I think you have missed some closing bracket, that could cause errors such as the one you got `can't find calculation()`

This below should work without issue, just make sure you don't have any open code brackets or parentheses anywhere.

```
void displayinvoice (std::vector<item> items, int item_count){    
    cout <<"**** INVOICE ****"<<endl;
    int i= 0;
    for (; i < item_count; i++){
        auto & cur_item = items.at(i);
        CalculationResult result = calculation(cur_item);
        cout << " ITEM ID        :" << cur_item.id<<endl; 
        /*......*/
    }
    cout << " ROUGH COST   : " << result.roughtotalprice << endl; // This one
    cout << " TOTAL PAYMENT : " << result.realprice <<endl;
}
```

main() body would look like this, but you will have to edit the `dataread()` to use `std::vector<item>` aswell:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<item> items;
    dataread(items,3);  
    displayinvoice(items, 3);
}
```

Comment: What happens to the loop inside of the main function? Should I remove it completely?

Comment: Just remove the loop from the main function and then add a call `displayinvoice(items, count)` in it's place.

Comment: I got errors like ``could not convert 'i' from 'int' to 'item' ``
and ``'count' was not declared in this scope (int main)``.
Can you show in detail?

Comment: Well you are not supposed to just copy paste `displayinvoice(items, count)`. You will have to make a count variable or just input a constant number.

Comment: Also, regarding the conversion issue. I had not seen that the input parameter  of `calculation()` was item, I had first thought it was an int. I have updated my answer accordingly.